# PHP Sybase, connect to remote server

Tags: php, database-connection, sybase

I am trying to find out whether it is possible or not to connect to a remote Sybase server using the Sybase PHP extension and the function [sybase_connect()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.sybase-connect.php).

Actually, I cannot find any explicit answer to this question on the internet. I tried using the function like this:

```
$con = sybase_connect('ip:port','sa','password');
```

but I keep getting the error:

> Warning: sybase_connect(): Sybase: Unable to connect in ...*

The server is reachable using a Sybase client such as Toad for Sybase for instance.

I am working with Windows 7 64bit and Wamp.

Would you please have any more details?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FreeTDS, I believe you need to add some settings to your `freetds.conf` file (mine is in /usr/local/etc/):

```
[ServerName]
    host = 1.2.3.4
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

"ServerName" can be anything you'd like. You should then be able to connect to it using `sybase_connect('ServerName','sa','password')`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know. I am working on Windows 7 with Wamp unfortunately...

Comment: I really struggle to install FreeTDS on my Wamp server on Windows 7. I have WampServer Version 2.5 and have PHP 5.5.12. I added the extension for php_dlib.dll in the PHP.ini and restarted Wamp but it doesn't like it is loading and I can't get an error message. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I installed FreeTDS on Windows and edited the freetds.conf file but it still not working. I also remove to semi-colon in front of the php extension `php_dblib.dll` but it doesn't show in php info. Do I really need this if I installed FreeTDS? Shall I try with older php version? Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah, sorry, I've got no idea how you'd do this in a Windows environment. You might want to update your question to point out that you're doing this on Windows.